# RXJS GroupBy in Angular 14 doesnt group

Tags: angular, rxjs

so in a basket I have:
[image]

As you can see there are 5 items. Two of the items have an id of 2.

So when I go to my basket view I want to group by the id and in the case of id 2 eventually want to too cost of 24.4.

So I thought I'd try to just get the group by id going first with the following.

The Basket component has:

```
photos$!: Observable<Array<Photo>>;

  constructor(private basketStore: Store<{ basket: Photo[] }>) {
    this.photos$ = this.basketStore.pipe(select(basket => basket.basket));
  }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.photos$.subscribe(() => this.basketStore.select(basketGroup));
  }
```

and in my selector I Have:

```
export interface basketSelection {
  basket: Photo[];
}

export const basketGroup = (state: basketSelection) => { return from(state.basket).pipe(groupBy(photo => photo.id)); }
```

then on my html file I have:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let photo of photos$ | async">
  <mat-card-content >
    {{photo.id}}
  </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

I thought I'd see id 2 once, but I just see 1, 2, 5, 2, 4.

Can anybody see why my groupby isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` is an RxJs stream operator, it creates a group from values emitted by an observable, you are wanting to group the values in an array.

Here is a quick and dirty group an array by id function

```
const groupById = array => array?.reduce((group, item) => {
  if (group[item.id]) {
    group[item.id].push(item);
  } else {
    group[item.id] = [item];
  }
  return group;
}, []);
```

here is a much more comprehensive group by function I wrote that supports complex keys and then bys.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez/blob/master/projects/ez-functions/src/lib/group-by.ts

You can npm install ez-functions and use it with `const group = groupBy(array, 'id');`